# How can I randomize probabilities in a random number generator?

Tags: c#, probability

In a normal random number generator, given a large enough sample, the average of the numbers generated will be close to the average of the number range specified. I'm trying to slow this down as I have a very large sample. So, to slow it down I'm thinking of randomizing the average that the generator will have but at the same time keeping the specified number range. Problem is that I'm struggling with randomizing the probability of the numbers in the specified range. Pseudo-ish example:

```
List<Tuple<int, double>> msProb = new List<Tuple<int, double>>();
for (int i = 20; i < 31; i++)
    {
        msProb.Add(new Tuple<int, double>(i, random());
    }
```

Comment: In statistics, there are different distributions of numbers.  The ["normal distribution"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is most commonly known, and is probably what you refer to in your first sentence.  Choose another distribution, and google that distribution followed by the terms "C# random number gen".

Comment: And what do you mean by "I'm trying to slow this down as I have a very large sample."?

Comment: If you just want to keep the distribution the same, can't you just use random.Next(yourMin, yourMax) ?

Comment: @Matt I think they want the center of min/max to be different from the average of the random numbers, which implies another distribution besides normal.  I could be mistaken in my interpretation though.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying now @Amy, deleting my answer, if average != median it's not a normal distribution. Deleting my answer.

Comment: @Amy Thanks, your answer is what I was looking for

Comment: @kaskelott I'm... glad that helped.  That was as far as my knowledge goes; it's been a decade since I took a stats class.

Comment: Eric Lippert has a series about "fixing random", would that help?

Comment: @Amy I actually think you mis-interpret the OP's first sentence. Ie. "In a 'normal' random number generator" is much more likely to refer to a ["uniform" distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8), not the "normal" distribution of statistics.

Comment: @chill94 Ah, yeah.  I think you're right.  "normal" in that sentence was more probably meant to indicate "typical"

Comment: @kaskelott - What is the problem you're trying to solve? Why is the convergence of the sample (or rather, the velocity of convergence) important?